# Using JavaScript to do something after you scroll an amount of pixels doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I followed this tutorial [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_shrink_header_scroll.asp) and edited it a little bit to change it to this:

```
    <script lang="text/javascript">
        // When the user scrolls down 50px from the top of the document, resize the header's font size
        window.onscroll = function () {
            scrollFunction()
        };

        function scrollFunction() {
            if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
                document.getElementById("header").style.display = "block";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("header").style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

With the header HTML being:

```
<div style="display: none;" id="header">Header</div>
```

When I try this in my .html file it will not work and doesn't even say a log in the console if I ask it to. I created a new HTML file with no reference to my CSS file and that worked so I think it is something to do with that, I don't know what though. Here is my CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    /*Want to change background image?*/
    /*Upload a new one to the img folder.*/
    /*Make sure you name it 'minecraft.jpg'*/
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(20, 26, 35, 0.55), rgba(20, 26, 35, 0.55)),
        url("../img/background.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}


#header {
    background-color: #f1f1f1; /* Grey background */
    padding: 50px 10px; /* Some padding */
    color: black;
    text-align: center; /* Centered text */
    font-size: 90px; /* Big font size */
    font-weight: bold;
    position: fixed; /* Fixed position - sit on top of the page */
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    transition: 0.2s; /* Add a transition effect (when scrolling - and font size is decreased) */
  }

html,
body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    /* color: rgb(0, 0, 0); */
}

.a-contact {
    text-decoration: underline !important;
    color: black;
}

.a-contact:hover {
    color: rgb(236, 149, 35);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px;
}

.container {
    text-align: center;
}

.logo img {
    width: 225px;
    /* Change image size for mobile */
    -webkit-animation-name: logo;
    animation-name: logo;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}


@-webkit-keyframes logo {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }

    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.07);
        transform: scale(1.07);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

@keyframes logo {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }

    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.07);
        transform: scale(1.07);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

.playercount {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px 15px 0 15px;
    padding: 2px 0;
    background-color: rgba(15, 199, 209, 0.75);
    font-size: 1em;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px 0 5px 0;
    line-height: 27px;
}

.playercount>p>span {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 1px 4px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: rgba(9, 150, 158, 0.7);
    margin: 0 2px;
}

.extrapad {
    padding: 0;
}

.ip {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.items {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
    justify-content: space-around;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100px;
    flex-basis: 100px;
    padding: 18px 0 10px 0;

}

.item img {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.item img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.img {
    width: 80%;
}

.title {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: white;
}

.subtitle {
    color: #cfcfcf;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.title,
.subtitle {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


@media(min-width: 400px) {
    .logo img {
        width: 280px;
        /* Change image size for mid sized devices */
    }

    .playercount {
        margin-top: 30px;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    .playercount>p>span {
        padding: 2px 7px;
    }
}

@media(min-width: 1250px) {
    .title {
        font-size: 24px;
    }

    .subtitle {
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    .logo img {
        width: 470px;
        /* Change image size for desktop */
    }

    .logo {
        margin-bottom: 28px;
    }

    .img {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .items {
        padding: 30px 0 20px 0;
    }

    .playercount {
        font-size: 1.22em;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .extrapad {
        padding: 0 42.5px;
    }

    .playercount>p>span {
        padding: 4px 7px;
    }
}

@media(min-width: 1000px) {
    .items {
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .item:not(:first-child) {
        margin-left: 90px;
    }
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 5px;
    top: 98%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
}

.background {
    /* background-color: rgb(187, 156, 53); */
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(255, 136, 0, 0.781), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 110%;
    height: 50%;
}

.background-white {
    /* background-color: rgb(187, 156, 53); */
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.781), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 220%;
    height: 50%;
}

.background-opposite {
    /* background-color: rgb(187, 156, 53); */
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(255, 136, 0, 0.781), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200%;
    height: 50%;
}
.background-white-opposite {
    /* background-color: rgb(187, 156, 53); */
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.781), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 310%;
    height: 50%;
}

.inner {
    background-color: rgba(255, 136, 0, 0.781);
    height: 40%;
    top: 160%;
    width: 100%;

    position: absolute;
}

.inner-white {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.781);
    height: 40%;
    top: 270%;
    width: 100%;

    position: absolute;
}

/* .inner-text {
    text-align: center;
} */

.inner-text-head {
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-size: 55px;
    text-align: center;
}

.inner-text-white-head {
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-size: 55px;
    text-align: center;
}

.inner-text-white-h2 {
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: center;
}

.contact-area {
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-color: black;
    border-style: dashed;
    border-width: 5px;
    width: 50% !important;
    left: 25% !important;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.inner-text-p {
    width: 75%;
    left: 13%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: black;
}

.inner-white-text-p {
    width: 75%;
    left: 13%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: black;
}

.solved {
    color: orange !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.italic {
    font-style: italic;
}


/* Scroll Down */
#s-scroll {
    position: relative;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
}

.chevroncontainer {
    position: absolute;
    /* margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; */
    top: 30%;
    /* right: 50%; */
    /* left: 50%; */
    /* top: 30%;
    left: -30%; */
}


.chevron {
    position: absolute;
    width: 38px;
    height: 30px;
    /* width: 56px;
      height: 36px; */
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    animation: move 0.2s ease-out infinite;
    animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-delay: calc(var(--scroll) * -1s);
    margin-left: -18px;
}

/* .chevroncontainer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100px !important;
  } */


.chevron:first-child {
    animation: move 0.2s ease-out 0.2s infinite;
    animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-delay: calc(var(--scroll) * -1s);
}

.chevron:nth-child(2) {
    animation: move 0.2s ease-out 0.2s infinite;
    animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-delay: calc(var(--scroll) * -1s);
}

/* CHEVRON CHANGED */
.changedchevron {
    position: absolute;
    width: 38px;
    height: 30px;
    /* width: 56px;
      height: 36px; */
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    animation: move 2s ease-out infinite;
    /* margin-left: -538px; */
    margin-left: -678px;
}



.changedchevronNO {
    position: absolute;
    width: 38px;
    height: 30px;
    /* width: 56px;
      height: 36px; */
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    animation: move 2s ease-out 1;
    margin-left: -18px;
}

/* .changedchevron:first-child {
      animation: move 2s ease-out 0.2s infinite;
    }
    
    .changedchevron:nth-child(2) {
      animation: move 2s ease-out 0.2s infinite;
    } */

.changedchevron:before,
.changedchevron:after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 40%;
    height: 40%;
    width: 51%;
    background: #fff;
}

.changedchevron:before {
    left: 0;
    transform: skew(0deg, 30deg);
}

.changedchevron:after {
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    transform: skew(0deg, -30deg);
}

/* CHEVRON CHANGED END */

.chevron:before,
.chevron:after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    height: 40%;
    width: 51%;
    background: #fff;
}

.chevron:before {
    left: 0;
    transform: skew(0deg, 30deg);
}

.chevron:after {
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    transform: skew(0deg, -30deg);
}

@keyframes move {
    25% {
        opacity: 1;

    }

    33% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(30px);
    }

    67% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(40px);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(55px) scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    }
}

.text {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 75px;
    margin-left: -30px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #fff !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    white-space: nowrap;
    opacity: .25;
    animation: pulse 2s linear alternate infinite;
    /* margin-left: -60px !important; */

    cursor: pointer !important;
    /* margin-left: -1058px; */
    margin-left: -1338px;
}

@keyframes pulse {
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

I'm sorry if this doesn't make any sense, I can't wrap my head around this problem either! Please tell me if you need more information and I can provide it.

Thanks!

Comment: Where's the > 50 for scrollTop in your argument? Ah.. I see it.. Hmm

Comment: Your initial state for your code is display: none which you have as a style in your div. Your JS code will display as a block past 50px, one issue is that you don't have any html apart from you header to cause a scroll much less at 50px. Add some lorem ipsum into a div as you see in the demo your mocking and the header will function as you have your code. It disappears and reappears.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed 2 things:

1. Rather than window you may want document.body - I'm sure you'd rather scroll body and not the entire window
2. Rather than .onscroll you may want .addEventListener - [Attaching JavaScript Handlers to Scroll Events — a how-NOT-to](https://www.benmarshall.me/attaching-javascript-handlers-to-scroll-events/)

Check out this snippet where I made those changes. I also made sure scrolling within a div wouldn't affect scrolling on document.body

```js
        
document.body.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  scrollFunction()
})

// When the user scrolls down 50px from the top of the document, resize the header's font size
        function scrollFunction() {
            if (document.body.scrollTop > 50 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
                document.getElementById("header").style.display = "block";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("header").style.display = "none";
            }
        }
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    /*Want to change background image?*/
    /*Upload a new one to the img folder.*/
    /*Make sure you name it 'minecraft.jpg'*/
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(20, 26, 35, 0.55), rgba(20, 26, 35, 0.55)),
        url("../img/background.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}


#header {
    background-color: #f1f1f1; /* Grey background */
    padding: 50px 10px; /* Some padding */
    color: black;
    text-align: center; /* Centered text */
    font-size: 90px; /* Big font size */
    font-weight: bold;
    position: fixed; /* Fixed position - sit on top of the page */
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    transition: 0.2s; /* Add a transition effect (when scrolling - and font size is decreased) */
  }

html,
body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    /* color: rgb(0, 0, 0); */
}

.a-contact {
    text-decoration: underline !important;
    color: black;
}

.a-contact:hover {
    color: rgb(236, 149, 35);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px;
}

.container {
    text-align: center;
}

.logo img {
    width: 225px;
    /* Change image size for mobile */
    -webkit-animation-name: logo;
    animation-name: logo;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}


@-webkit-keyframes logo {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }

    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.07);
        transform: scale(1.07);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

@keyframes logo {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }

    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.07);
        transform: scale(1.07);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

.playercount {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px 15px 0 15px;
    padding: 2px 0;
    background-color: rgba(15, 199, 209, 0.75);
    font-size: 1em;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px 0 5px 0;
    line-height: 27px;
}

.playercount>p>span {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 1px 4px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: rgba(9, 150, 158, 0.7);
    margin: 0 2px;
}

.extrapad {
    padding: 0;
}

.ip {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.items {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
    justify-content: space-around;
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100px;
    flex-basis: 100px;
    padding: 18px 0 10px 0;

}

.item img {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.item img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.img {
    width: 80%;
}

.title {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: white;
}

.subtitle {
    color: #cfcfcf;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.title,
.subtitle {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


@media(min-width: 400px) {
    .logo img {
        width: 280px;
        /* Change image size for mid sized devices */
    }

    .playercount {
        margin-top: 30px;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    .playercount>p>span {
        padding: 2px 7px;
    }
}

@media(min-width: 1250px) {
    .title {
        font-size: 24px;
    }

    .subtitle {
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    .logo img {
        width: 470px;
        /* Change image size for desktop */
    }

    .logo {
        margin-bottom: 28px;
    }

    .img {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .items {
        padding: 30px 0 20px 0;
    }

    .playercount {
        font-size: 1.22em;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .extrapad {
        padding: 0 42.5px;
    }

    .playercount>p>span {
        padding: 4px 7px;
    }
}

@media(min-width: 1000px) {
    .items {
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .item:not(:first-child) {
        margin-left: 90px;
    }
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 5px;
    top: 98%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
}

.background {
    /* background-color: rgb(187, 156, 53); */
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(255, 136, 0, 0.781), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 110%;
    height: 50%;
}

.background-white {
    /* background-color: rgb(187, 156, 53); */
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.781), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 220%;
    height: 50%;
}

.background-opposite {
    /* background-color: rgb(187, 156, 53); */
    background: linear-gradient(rgb(255, 136, 0, 0.781), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200%;
    height: 50%;
}
.background-white-opposite {
    /* background-color: rgb(187, 156, 53); */
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.781), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 310%;
    height: 50%;
}

.inner {
    background-color: rgba(255, 136, 0, 0.781);
    height: 40%;
    top: 160%;
    width: 100%;

    position: absolute;
}

.inner-white {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.781);
    height: 40%;
    top: 270%;
    width: 100%;

    position: absolute;
}

/* .inner-text {
    text-align: center;
} */

.inner-text-head {
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-size: 55px;
    text-align: center;
}

.inner-text-white-head {
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-size: 55px;
    text-align: center;
}

.inner-text-white-h2 {
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: center;
}

.contact-area {
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-color: black;
    border-style: dashed;
    border-width: 5px;
    width: 50% !important;
    left: 25% !important;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.inner-text-p {
    width: 75%;
    left: 13%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: black;
}

.inner-white-text-p {
    width: 75%;
    left: 13%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: black;
}

.solved {
    color: orange !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.italic {
    font-style: italic;
}


/* Scroll Down */
#s-scroll {
    position: relative;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
}

.chevroncontainer {
    position: absolute;
    /* margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; */
    top: 30%;
    /* right: 50%; */
    /* left: 50%; */
    /* top: 30%;
    left: -30%; */
}


.chevron {
    position: absolute;
    width: 38px;
    height: 30px;
    /* width: 56px;
      height: 36px; */
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    animation: move 0.2s ease-out infinite;
    animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-delay: calc(var(--scroll) * -1s);
    margin-left: -18px;
}

/* .chevroncontainer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100px !important;
  } */


.chevron:first-child {
    animation: move 0.2s ease-out 0.2s infinite;
    animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-delay: calc(var(--scroll) * -1s);
}

.chevron:nth-child(2) {
    animation: move 0.2s ease-out 0.2s infinite;
    animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-delay: calc(var(--scroll) * -1s);
}

/* CHEVRON CHANGED */
.changedchevron {
    position: absolute;
    width: 38px;
    height: 30px;
    /* width: 56px;
      height: 36px; */
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    animation: move 2s ease-out infinite;
    /* margin-left: -538px; */
    margin-left: -678px;
}



.changedchevronNO {
    position: absolute;
    width: 38px;
    height: 30px;
    /* width: 56px;
      height: 36px; */
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    animation: move 2s ease-out 1;
    margin-left: -18px;
}

/* .changedchevron:first-child {
      animation: move 2s ease-out 0.2s infinite;
    }
    
    .changedchevron:nth-child(2) {
      animation: move 2s ease-out 0.2s infinite;
    } */

.changedchevron:before,
.changedchevron:after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 40%;
    height: 40%;
    width: 51%;
    background: #fff;
}

.changedchevron:before {
    left: 0;
    transform: skew(0deg, 30deg);
}

.changedchevron:after {
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    transform: skew(0deg, -30deg);
}

/* CHEVRON CHANGED END */

.chevron:before,
.chevron:after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    height: 40%;
    width: 51%;
    background: #fff;
}

.chevron:before {
    left: 0;
    transform: skew(0deg, 30deg);
}

.chevron:after {
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    transform: skew(0deg, -30deg);
}

@keyframes move {
    25% {
        opacity: 1;

    }

    33% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(30px);
    }

    67% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(40px);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(55px) scale3d(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    }
}

.text {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 75px;
    margin-left: -30px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #fff !important;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    white-space: nowrap;
    opacity: .25;
    animation: pulse 2s linear alternate infinite;
    /* margin-left: -60px !important; */

    cursor: pointer !important;
    /* margin-left: -1058px; */
    margin-left: -1338px;
}

@keyframes pulse {
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<div style="display: none;" id="header">Header</div>


<div style="width: 100px; height: 500px; overflow: scroll">
  test<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>test
</div>
```